# What steps should I take while doing this logarithmic differentiation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y = {\tan{4 \sin^2(5 e+9)\over e^5+\tan 33°}}+{\sqrt[7]{\ln {{\sin 2x - \cos (e-x^2)}\over \cos^33x}}}+e^{5-9x \ln e}$$

In the end I need to have $y'$

Like honestly I don't even know where to start..?

Comment: Honestly, I would never even begin to differentiate that horrid looking thing by hand. If you must, you can note that the first term does not depend on $x$ and hence vanishes after differentiation with respect to $x$. To differentiate the other terms the easiest is probably multiple uses of the chain rule.

Comment: University kills me...

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed. Should I delete the post?

Comment: No, don't delete the question. Others can learn from it, and someone may also give an answer that helps more.

Comment: Chain rule is your friend. It is not too hard, just start differentiating $(f)^{1/7}$.

Comment: This is *not* a hard problem. You are just intimidated by its appearance. The first term is constant, and the last term is a constant times $e^{-9x}$, so only the middle term needs work. For starters, it's of the form $(\log f(x))^c$, so work with that...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: simbolically the mid term can be written as

$$(g\circ h)^c$$

where $c=1/7$, $g=\ln$ and $h=\frac{\sin (f_1)-\cos(f_2)}{(\cos (f_3))^3}$. And you know that

$$[(f)^c]'= c(f)^{c-1}f',\quad\text{and}\quad (g\circ h)'=(g'\circ h)h'$$

and

$$[\ln(f)]'=\frac{f'}{f},\quad [\sin(f)]'=f'\cos(f),\quad\text{and}\quad[\cos(f)]'=-f'\sin(f)$$

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments and answers, only the middle term is problematic 
$$A={\sqrt[7]{\ln {{\sin (2x) - \cos (e-x^2)}\over \cos^3(3x)}}}\implies A^7={\ln {{\sin (2x) - \cos (e-x^2)}\over \cos^3(3x)}}$$ $$e^{A^7}={{\sin (2x) - \cos (e-x^2)}\over \cos^3(3x)}\implies 7A^6 e^{A^7} A'=\left({{\sin (2x) - \cos (e-x^2)}\over \cos^3(3x)}\right)'$$